# (change ) function on element is called with change in parent object of ngModel in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

(change ) function on element is called with parent object of ngModel change angular 2.
this is how I assigned model

```
(change)="OnScheduleChange(confirmSchedule)" 
[(ngModel)]="AddMedMod.schedule.numberOfDaysOn"
```

Now whenever I make any change to the parent object i.e to AddMedMod.schedule then **OnScheduleChange(confirmSchedule)** is called automatically which should not be called. any idea how to avoid it

Even the value of the **AddMedMod.schedule.numberOfDaysOn** remains the same

Comment: so that is what I found reason behind it
First we need to understand that change is not an “Angular event”, it’s a DOM event.
Whereas ngModelChange is an Angular event. It fires when ngModel changes.
so ngModelChange  is only called when actual value is changed Read mote here https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/difference-change-ngmodelchange-angular

Comment: What/Where is OnScheduleChange(confirmSchedule). Please provide detail.

Comment: @Meh that was added but was not showing due to editor issue .my issue has been solved. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so that is what I found reason behind it First we need to understand that **change** is not an “Angular event”, it’s a DOM event. Whereas **ngModelChange** is an Angular event. It fires when **ngModel** changes. so **ngModelChange** is only called when actual value is changed

```
(ngModelChange)="OnScheduleChange(confirmSchedule)" 
[(ngModel)]="AddMedMod.schedule.numberOfDaysOn"
```

Read mote here
*https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/difference-change-ngmodelchange-angular*